# phpmyadmin is not working after installing mysql workbench

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have been working with php and I use phpmyadmin for database.Then I installed mysql workbench to work further with mysql. But now after installing mysql workbench phpmyadmin is not working.I get the following error.

MySQL said: Documentation

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  Connection for controluser as
>   defined in your configuration failed.  mysqli_real_connect():
>   (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)  phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and
>   the server rejected the connection. You should check the host,
>   username and password in your configuration and make sure that they
>   correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL
>   server

how do I rectify this error?

Comment: `the server rejected the connection` For me, this sounds like credentials might be correct but the host you're connecting from is not allowed to connect. Try manually connecting via console and take a look at the user table.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide few steps

1. Suppose your mysql workbench port is 3306, try changing port number for xampp mysql by editing my.ini file and change all port number appearance to something different (let's say 3300)
2. Also "open service and port settings" from xampp > config > open service and port settings. change port number (to 3300)
3. Open Mysql workbench and add "New Connection" (port number, hostname, connection name , set password or blank ) while running xampp
   [image: adding new connection]
4. Open xampp folder > phpmyadmin > config.inc.php > Add port number after 127.0.0.1  ( $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3300';)
5. Try running xampp as administrator